# How to read a verbose:GC output?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

70.222: [GC [PSYoungGen: 131072K->15437K(152896K)] 131072K->15509K(502464K), 0.0228420 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can find tutorials on interpreting verbose GC output eg. in:

- [verbosegc output tutorial - Java 7](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/10/verbosegc-output-tutorial-java-7.html)
- [Heap settings and reading verbose GC output](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/heap-settings-and-reading-verbose-gc-output/)

Looking at [verbosegc output tutorial - Java 7](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/10/verbosegc-output-tutorial-java-7.html), you can see **YoungGen space analysis**:

**UPDATE 03/27/2014:** The "**Collection time (secs)**" is actually a Timestamp showing the when the GC occurred. The Collection times are reported as `Times=user=0.45 sys=0.01, real=0.14 secs]`.

[image]

Here, the `262208K->137900K(100428K)` means `Java Heap before GC`-> `Java Heap after GC (Total Size of the Java Heap)`.

And, **OldGen space analysis**:

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that 131072K (young gen before)->15437K (young gen after)(152896K)]  131072K (java heap before)->15509K(502464K) (java heap after),    ??? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: The number on the left is not the collection time. But, it's the timestamp representing the time since java process is running.

Comment: You are correct, wow, there is a mistake. Timestamp is so essential to me that I did not check it in that picture... will put an update there.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot upgrade the diagram so I have added an explanation.

Comment: Use -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, you will get the actual time when the process is running rather than the time elasped. I find it more useful.

Comment: Yep, that's correct! We switched all our GC logs to `-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`

Answer (score 14):

In Addition to other answer , I am explaining Times section of log

[Times: user=0.09 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]

The “Times” section of the detailed log contains information about the CPU time used by the GC, separated into user space (“user”) and kernel space (“sys”) of the operating system.Also, it shows the real time (“real”) that passed while the GC was running.

In your case the CPU time (0.09 sec) is considerably higher than the real time passed (0.02 Sec), we can conclude that the GC was run using multiple threads.

[Detailed Example](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/)