# Could you please explain this GC log message?

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection

> 2013-12-15T22:52:05.154-0500: 1.078: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen:
>   1600K->0K(27776K)] [PSOldGen: 0K->1502K(63360K)] 1600K->1502K(91136K)
>   [PSPermGen: 9139K->9139K(65536K)], 0.0282750 secs] [Times: user=0.03
>   sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]

Above is the log snippet  from the log file. I got the log by adding the jvm parameter like below.

```
-Xloggc:/tmp/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

For now I want to know what's the meaning of

> [PSOldGen: 0K->1502K(63360K)] 1600K->1502K(91136K)

How does it happen?

Comment: You went from having no (`0K`) Old Generation, to having some (`1502K`) Old Generation.

Comment: what's 1600K->1502K? Why no square bracket？

Comment: 1600K was allocated, 1502K is now used. As for the lack of square bracket... I must confess ignorance.

Comment: Does the 1600K->1502K mean the memory change of whole heap memory including young and old gen?

Answer (score 4):

This log line indicates that a Full GC was invoked by calling `System.gc()`.

1502K was promoted from YoungGen to OldGen. 1600K->1502K(91136K) indicates total Heap usage going from 1600K to 1502K, total heap size 91136K.

See [Java Garbage Collection Log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/895444/772000) and [How to read a verbose:GC output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16794783/772000) for more details.

Comment: is (63360K) allocated or max memory?

Comment: Thats the size of the OldGen memory area.