# what is effect of this in gc log?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I viewed gc log, some of the information is as follows:

`1182.030: [GC[YG occupancy: 8729512 K (9216000 K)]1182.030: [Rescan (parallel) , 7.6001940 secs]1189.630: [weak refs processing, 0.0000190 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 262120K(436904K)] 8991632K(9652904K), 7.6004580 secs] [Times: user=86.06 sys=0.42, real=7.60 secs]`

`13901.282: [GC 13901.283: [ParNew: 8766574K->400883K(9216000K), 1.9300940 secs] 10239467K->1917256K(11578944K), 1.9309390 secs] [Times: user=13.68 sys=0.07, real=1.93 secs]`

I have some doubt，My question is:

- What is effect "times" very large?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794783/how-to-read-a-verbosegc-output

Comment: I know,but "times" is very large in my log. what is effect for this?

Comment: The effect is that your program pauses for the "real" times.