# java is PSYoungGen a stop the world event

Tags: java, garbage-collection, verbosegc

are these stop the world events, for my a java application / jvm
and if so which one.  user sys real,

[PSYoungGen: 347808K->672K(348160K)] 415832K->68744K(1047552K), 0.0019772 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

[PSYoungGen: 347808K->640K(348160K)] 415880K->68792K(1 047552K), 0.0018775 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs]

[PSYoungGen: 347776K->704K(348160K)] 415928K->68912K(1047552K), 0.0020238 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections of most of Garbage Collector implementations do "stop the world" events.

For example, the default Garbage Collector implementation used on a JVM 1.7 is G1 and you can read in the [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html) that it does "stop the world" pauses for young generation collection :

> The G1 GC has a pause time-target that it tries to meet (soft real time). During young collections, the G1 GC adjusts its young generation (eden and survivor sizes) to meet the soft real-time target.

The real difference is how long the stop has elapsed. You have the other responses here : [How to read a verbose:GC output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794783/how-to-read-a-verbosegc-output)

Edit :  I precised the "most of" GC implementations (not all) and illustrated with the G1 example.